# How do I use the Facebook API to query whether posting is permitted on a user's wall?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

I'm designing a web app that allows people to post on peoples wall using the Facebook Graph API.  Basically my app users will be able to search for people by name, then write a message and finally post it to their wall.

The problem is that in certain cases people on Facebook block the option for others to post on their wall. So when sending the post from my app Facebook will return an error.

My question is whether the Facebook API returns a parameter that states whether or not it's possible to post to somebody's wall based on their permission on Facebook.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The [FQL `user` table](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/user/) has a field called `can_post`:

> can_post | bool | Whether or not the viewer can post to the user's Wall.

Comment: My app will also be posting to events and groups (not only to users). Do you happen to know if there is a "can_post" equivalent to events and groups as well?

Comment: No, not directly. I think you might have to check the privacy of the group/event first, and if it’s not public, you’d have to check if the user is a member of the group/participant in the event …

Comment: Thanks again. Tried to do that, but if the event is not public, the app would not be able to retrieve the list of users participating in the event)

Comment: Well that will depend on what kind of access token you’re using. For a non-public event, it would have to be an access token from the creator of the event or a user who is allowed to see it.